# How to show new activity(screen) using WorkManager

Tags: java, android-intent, android-workmanager

**MyWorker.class:**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d("TAG","WORK: ");
        //my actual work....

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewScreen.class);
       getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

        return Result.success(); //true - success / false - failure
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

        oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build())
                .build();


        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
    }
}
```

I am trying to open a new activity(screen) from the MainActivity using WorkManager. Trying to learn and experiment with WorkManager. The logs if I enter run i.e the doWork() gets executed. Also I added breakpoint on intent and it worked but the UI doesnt gets affected.

FYI - I am new and learning WorkManager and Background processes.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally figured out a solution for my problem:**

- Need to use a

> Handler

to pass & run the work from the Background thread to the Main thread.

- Need to use

> intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

as I have been calling the intent outside of the Activity context.

- Add Looper as a parameter in

> Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

because if you create a handler in a non UI thread you will post messages to the non UI Thread. A handler by default post message to the thread where it is created.
- Use the context of the constructor of the Worker class that is created.

**Solution Code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

import static android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;


public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    Context mcontext;

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.mcontext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d("TAG","WORK: ");
        //my actual work....

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, NewScreen.class);
                intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return Result.success(); //true - success / false - failure
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work when your app is in background for android 10+